# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'innerText')

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, fetch

I want a table reading data from an API. I created a script and everything works fine but in console I receive two errors and don't know why. The second error is underlined in red the first one is not.
Thanks in advance

**HTML**

```
     <div class="rebeltable">
        <table id="rebeltable">
            <thead>
                <td class="col-span-1">nome</td>
                <td class="col-span-1">cognome</td>
                <td class="col-span-1">data di nascita</td>
                <td class="col-span-1">email</td>
                <td class="col-span-1">qualifica</td>
                <td class="col-span-1">username</td>
                <td class="col-span-1">password</td>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                
            </tbody>
        </table>
     </div>
```

**-- JAVASCRIPT --**

```
    const tabella = document.getElementById('rebeltable')
    const tbody = tabella.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0]
    const tdhead = tabella.getElementsByTagName('thead')[0].childNodes[1].children  
 

    async function getUser(url){
    const response = await fetch(url)
    const resolve = await response.json()

    createTable(resolve) // first error in console not underlined

    }
    getUser('https://random-data-api.com/api/v2/users?size=10&response_type=json')


    function createTable(data) { 
    let tabellaDati = []
    let tabellaGriglia = []
    const asseX = tdhead.length
    const asseY = data.length

    for(let i=0; i<data.length; i++) { 
       let nome = data[i].first_name
       let cognome = data[i].last_name
       let dataNascita = data[i].date_of_birth
       let email = data[i].email
       let qualifica = data[i].employment.title 
       let userName = data[i].username 
       let password = data[i].password
      
       tabellaDati.push([[nome, cognome, dataNascita, email, qualifica, userName, password]])

        const riga = document.createElement('tr')
        
        tabellaGriglia.push(riga) // inserisco tante righe vuote quanti i record in "data" 

        for(k=0; k<tdhead.length; k++) { // tdhead.length numero di colonne ovvero 7 
            const cella = document.createElement('td')  
            riga.appendChild(cella)
        }
         
        tbody.appendChild(riga)
       
     }; 
     
    // console.log(tabellaDati);
    

    const singleCell = tbody.getElementsByTagName("td");
   
     for (let index = 0; index < asseY; index++) {
       singleCell[7*index].innerText = tabellaDati[index][0][0]  
      
        for (let k = 1; k < asseY; k++) {

        singleCell[(7*index)+k].innerText = tabellaDati[index][0][k]  
        // here the second error  tabellaDati[index][0][k] is underlined in red

       }
      }

    }
```

**CONSOLE**
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'innerText')
at createTable (app.js:62:43)
at getUser (app.js:17:5)

createTable @ app.js:62
getUser @ app.js:17
await in getUser (asinc)
(anonimo) @ app.js:19

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At some point value before .innerText is undefined in your case...Try adding a optional chaining operator "?" before each .innerText like

`singleCell[7*index].innerText` will become `singleCell[7*index]?.innerText`

Comment: Thanks but didn't work, now console says "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment (at app.js:60:9)"

Comment: I see.. its because you are assigning some value to innerText,

try this:

if(singleCell[7*index]) {
singleCell[7*index].innerText = tabellaDati[index][0][0] 
}

and same for below one

Comment: It worked!! You were right, checking the existence with if() solved. But it's not so clear why not before... anyway thanks

Comment: you can ask friend what needed to be clear?